# maximize $x^a + y^b$ subject to $p_1x+p_2y=w$ utility max.

Tags: optimization

This is a utility maximzation problem

maximize $x^a + y^b$ subject to $p_1x+p_2y=w$ (utility maximization problem)

Anyone has any idea, there are no restrictions on $a$ and $b$, as far as i can see it. many thanks!!!

Comment: what is $p_1$,$p_2$?

Comment: constants, prices, strictly positive.

Comment: I am surprized that there is no restrictions on "x" and "y". AQre there illimited resources ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Lagrange multipliers but I think that the problem could be easy if you extract "y" from the constraint and plug it in the objective function which becomes only dependent on "x". Now, serach for the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

When consumers maximize utility $u(x,y)=x^a+y^b$ with respect to a budget constraint $p_1x+p_2y=w$, the indifference curve is tangent to the budget line, therefore:
$$ MRS_{xy}=p_1/p_2 $$
with $MRS_{xy}=\frac{u_x}{x_y}$ and 
$$\begin{align}
u_x&=\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}=ax^{a-1}\\
u_y&=\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=by^{b-1}\\
\end{align}$$
that is
$$
\frac{p_1}{p_2}=\frac{ax^{a-1}}{by^{b-1}}
$$
So the optimal $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ are solution of
$$
\begin{align}
w&=p_1\hat{x}+p_2\left(\frac{p_2}{p_1}\frac{a}{b}\hat{x}^{a-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{b-1}}\\
w&=p_1\left(\frac{p_1}{p_2}\frac{b}{a}\hat{y}^{b-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{a-1}}+p_2\hat{y}\\
\end{align}
$$

Comment: that's about as far as I got. From there I am stuck, I am simply not able to derive a reduced form solution for neither x nor y.

Comment: the solution cannot be solved in elementary form...unless you give other conditions on $a$ and $b$...

Comment: I understand. So is there a reduced form solution for a,b both element of (0,1).?